# Nhibernate session in Ninject RequestScope

Tags: nhibernate, ninject

Just a quick question. If I have a binding like so:

```
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionManager>().GetSession()).InRequestScope();
```

(Assuming that ISessionManager.GetSession() returns SessionFactory.OpenSession())

Do I need to explicitly close the session? or will it automatically dispose itself when Ninject deems it out of scope?

Comment: I think the answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243228/will-ninject-call-dispose-and-close-the-nhibernate-isession

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Ninject call dispose and close the NHibernate Isession?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243228/will-ninject-call-dispose-and-close-the-nhibernate-isession)

Comment: not a possible, it is a duplicate... couldnt find the initial question you have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ISession` implements `IDisposable` Ninject will call it , And I think it does.

Latest Source code : http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs?revision=5765&view=markup

Comment: Its NHibernate.ISession, so yes it does!