# FluentNHibernate Session Management in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, nhibernate, singleton, sessionfactory, nhibernate-burrow

New to NHibernate(my disclaimer). I came across a similar and interesting [article regarding MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364540/nhibernate-session-management-in-asp-net-mvc), however, I'm more curious as to what general best practices are for managing NHibernate sessions within a generic web application.

I've come across the [Burrow](http://nhforge.org/wikis/burrow/default.aspx) project, but I'm starting to realize there seems to be a few different directions to take. I'm aware it's probably not in my best interest to [create a new SessionFactory](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Your_first_project) every time I need to touch the database, so I'm interested in what the community does to manage sessions. Do you use Burrow? Do you wrap your SessionFactory in a singleton?

Any direction or insight is always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question directly, your `ISessionFactory` object should be a singleton. You can either do this programmatically (i.e. by wrapping it in a C# singleton) or by configuring it in your IoC container.

As for sessions, Burrow looks good but the prodominant and simplest pattern for sessions in web applications - OpenSessionInView - comes out-of-the-box with NHibernate 2.0.0. That is, your data access code calls `ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` rather than `ISessionFactory.OpenSession()`. You then state how the factory's *current session* is managed by specifying an implementation of `ICurrentSessionContext`. NHibernate provides two out-of-the box ones for alligning the session with the web request. This is known as 'Contextual Sessions' in the documentation.

No doubt a more complex web application might require more longer lasting conversations with complex lazy loading etc., but for a standard web application NHibernate contextual sessions should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a series of blog posts on this topic regarding with NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate Data Access patterns.

The first I recommend is abstract away the interaction of NHibernate.

[Creating a common generic and extensible NHiberate Repository](http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/creating-a-common-generic-and-extensible-nhiberate-repository/)

Then for handling session management I implemented the "Session per Business Conversation" pattern which instead of having a NH session exist for the life of a single page request that is a common one it exists for a series of events say a page that allows you to make a bunch of edits to a form and then at the end either apply them all permanently or cancel them.

[Conversation Per Business Transaction using PostSharp and IoC](http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/conversation-per-business-transaction-using-postsharp-and-ioc/)

If I was going to write this post today, I wouldn't use PostSharp again to handle the AOP (Aspect Orientated Programming) code in my project I'd either use [Linfu.AOP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart6.aspx) or another framework to do the AOP interaction.

Comment: 'Creating a common generic and extensible NHiberate Repository' was a great read.